# Are docker environment variables shared between containers?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

Newbie here. I created an empty solution, added WebApplication1 and WebApplication2. I then added docker support (Docker for Windows, Windows Containers). Compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapplication1:
    image: compositeapp
    build:
      context: .\WebApplication1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  webapplication2:
    image: compositeapp
    build:
      context: .\WebApplication2
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

So both containers are in a single image. Webapplication1 dockerfile has ENV LICENSE=abc123 and webapplication2 dockerfile has ENV LICENSE=abc456.

After building and starting the containers, I used exec -it powershell to remote into the 2 containers and did get-item env:license. Both containers returned 456.

As a newbie, I was expecting one machine to return abc123 and the other abc456. I just made up the environment name as being license, but what does one do if they need a per container environment variable?

Comment: How do you set the two environment variables?

Comment: @tkausl I said in the question.. in each project's dockerfile ENV LICENSE=value

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue you notice provides from the fact you specified the same image name for both services, which implies that they will have the same `ENV` variable as defined in the latest-compiled `Dockerfile`.

Could you try this instead?

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapplication1:
    image: compositeapp1
    build:
      context: .\WebApplication1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  webapplication2:
    image: compositeapp2
    build:
      context: .\WebApplication2
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Anyway, even if this is working, I assume your two `Dockerfile` are almost the same (?), in which case I would rather suggest to use a single `Dockerfile` and a single image tag, but customize the environment of both services by using some [environment](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#environment) section in your `docker-compose.yml` (or some [env_file](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#env_file) section, along with some external `.env` files...).

For example, you may want to write something like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapplication1:
    image: compositeapp
    build:
      context: .\WebApplication
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - LICENSE=abc123
  webapplication2:
    image: compositeapp
    environment:
      - LICENSE=abc456
```

(not forgetting to remove the `ENV LICENSE=...` line from the `Dockerfile`)

Comment: Using the same image name was the intention to build a composite image. It does actually work as expected when I use docker-compose.override.yml… for some reason doesn't even build in docker-compose.yml??? Very weird.

Comment: @SledgeHammer I'm not sure I follow you, because if you use exactly the same image name as in your example, you should expect the two services use the same image, and thereby have the same behavior?

Comment: when I use the same image name, it creates 2 containers (1 for each web app), but they live in the same image as expected. If I remote into each container, they have their own OS files, inetpub, etc. What I was trying to do was set LICENSE=xxx for web app 1 and LICENSE=yyy for web app 2. When I do it in the two docker files, the last ENV LICENSE= wins... when I do it in the compose override as you showed, each container gets its own environment var as expected.

Comment: @SledgeHammer Indeed, with the two versions of `docker-compose.yml` we considered, `docker-compose` behaves as expected. Actually, I am more and more convinced that your use case could be addressed by using a single `Dockerfile`, a single image name, and extra environment sections in the `docker-compose.yml`: see the end of my answer where I just added one such example.

Comment: as I mentioned in one of the comments, if I put the environment line in docker-compose.yml, it actually doesn't even build (gets an error). It has to go into the docker-compose.override for some reason. The 2 dockerfiles are identical, just VS2017 creates one for each project.

Comment: @SledgeHammer You just said "it doesn't even build (gets an error)" but didn't mention the error; so one couldn't figure out what happens without further details. Moreover, the second `Dockerfile` example I proposed works for me, so maybe you are encountering an orthogonal issue w.r.t. what is discussed in this SO question...

Comment: ...anyway FYI the usage of `docker-compose.override.yml` is documented here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files

Comment: Also @SledgeHammer I'd say that to deploy 2 similar applications with different environment variables, you only have 2 cases: either the codebase of both services is exactly the same, so the image name can be the same and you just need to override the env variables of the containers (reusing my 2nd example of Dockerfile or looking at https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/); or the 2 services correspond to different programs (2 projects with a different codebase), **in which case it is mandatory that you choose 2 different image names** (reusing my first example of Dockerfile).